# Navigation bar now showing in other activity

Tags: android, xml

i got error log like this, actually im try to show DrawableToggle in other xml, but the problem like this, and error log shown in post too

im already have some activity with navigation bar in acitivity main and its show toggle bar

but when i try implement in another xml, toggle bar not show up

manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.felix.tgp" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="com.felix.tgp.AppController">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Calculator"
            android:label="Body Mass Index Calculator"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.felix.tgp.MainList"
            android:label="Chest Workout"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

style.xml

```
    <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#FF39A3EB</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#FF185896</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

calculator.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Title"
                android:layout_weight="0.75"
                android:layout_x="0dp"
                android:layout_y="22dp"
                android:text="BMI Calculator"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="50dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Height"
                android:id="@+id/TextView"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="158dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:id="@+id/height"
                android:hint="cm"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColorHint="#898484" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Weight"
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_x="77dp"
                android:layout_y="168dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="158dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/weight"
                android:layout_x="183dp"
                android:layout_y="154dp"
                android:hint="Kg"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColorHint="#898484" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="147dp"
                android:layout_height="68dp"
                android:text="Calculate"
                android:id="@+id/hitung"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="158dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/result"
                android:hint="Result"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColorHint="#898484" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/finalresult"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColorHint="#898484"
                android:scrollbars = "vertical"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_calculator) {
            // Handle the camera action
            Intent calculator = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Calculator.class);
            startActivity(calculator);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_chest) {
            Intent List = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainList.class);
            startActivity(List);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_back) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_shoulder) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_arm) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_abdominal) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_leg) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

calculator.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Felix on 3/2/2016.
 */
public class Calculator extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    private Button hitung;
    private TextView result, finalresult;
    private EditText height,weight;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calculator);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        hitung = (Button)findViewById(R.id.hitung);
        height = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.height);
        weight = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.weight);
        result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
        finalresult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.finalresult);

        finalresult.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        hitung.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String tinggi = height.getText().toString();
        String berat = weight.getText().toString();
        double hasilakhir = Double.parseDouble(berat)/((Double.parseDouble(tinggi)*0.01)*(Double.parseDouble(tinggi)*0.01));
        result.setText(String.format("%.2f", hasilakhir));
        String bmiindex =   "Keterangan BMI\n" +
                "BMI < 18.5 = Berat Badan Anda dibawah rata-rata (underweight)\n" +
                "BMI 18.5 - 24 = Berat Badan Anda normal\n" +
                "BMI 25 - 29 = Kelebihan Berat Badan (overweight)\n" +
                "BMI >30 = Anda Tergolong Obesitas";
        if(hasilakhir < 18.5 ){
            finalresult.setText("Berat Badan Anda dibawah rata-rata (underweight)\n"+"\n" +bmiindex);
        }
        else if(hasilakhir >=18.5 && hasilakhir <=24.99) {
            finalresult.setText("Berat Badan Anda normal\n"+"\n" +bmiindex);
        }
        else if(hasilakhir >=25 && hasilakhir <=29.99) {
            finalresult.setText("Kelebihan Berat Badan (overweight)\n"+"\n" +bmiindex);
        }
        else if(hasilakhir >=30){
            finalresult.setText("Anda Tergolong Obesitas\n"+"\n" +bmiindex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_calculator) {
            // Handle the camera action
            Intent calculator = new Intent(Calculator.this, Calculator.class);
            startActivity(calculator);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_chest) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_back) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_shoulder) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_arm) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_abdominal) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_leg) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Log error

```
     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.felix.tgp, PID: 2255
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.felix.tgp/com.felix.tgp.Calculator}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:100)
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:93)
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.<init>(ToolbarActionBar.java:78)
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:206)
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:99)
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.felix.tgp.Calculator.onCreate(Calculator.java:39)
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
04-20 12:37:30.940 2255-2255/com.felix.tgp E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
04-20 12:37:32.180 2255-2255/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2255 SIG: 9
```

Comment: With just one drawer, your `DrawerLayout` should have only two direct child `View`s - the main content, and the drawer. In the `calculator` layout, you have three: `app_bar_main`, `nav_view`, and the `LinearLayout`. The `LinearLayout`, being listed after the `nav_view`, is z-ordered on top of the drawer.

Comment: so what must i do? because im new in this AS

Comment: @MikeM. can you do this for me please, actually im only want show triple line like image1 i post, and show up in calculator.xml and when im click the triple lines its open navigation drawer like images 2

Comment: If you're not getting the triple line, then you've not setup the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` correctly. Post that code, and we can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks for help, actually im using default Android Studio navigation drawer when create project, i didnt find ActioanBarDrawerToggle ._.

Comment: Well, I can't help you without seeing your code, as I don't know what Android Studio's default Navigation Drawer project entails. Someone else might, though.

Comment: @MikeM. sorry my bad i found it lol really" sorry but i have problem, check my post

Comment: done :) but got some error check log

Comment: In your manifest, the `Calculator` `<activity>` needs to have the same `theme` as `MainActivity`.

Comment: change with android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar", same like .MainActivity manifest themes but still got error

Comment: Then either the code didn't refresh, compile, and reinstall correctly, or it's a different error.

Comment: im try restart and still same, please check again on my post, its completed all code i have

Comment: `toolbar` is `null` in `Calculator`, because you've removed the `app_bar_main` `<include>` from `Calculator`'s layout.

Comment: ohh cool, its works, but how about im only want to show toggle but not layout?

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying.

Comment: @MikeM. i mean its comes with content main.xml too when on content main has a some text "hello world", containt main is use when your open application

Comment: @MikeM. im relly" thanks full you want help to resolve my problem :) and i have some problem, when im in calculator layout, why the navigation bar not work , i mean when im click like chest its not moving into another activity

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're saying, but if you just want to remove the "Hello World!", look in your layouts for a `<TextView>` that has a `text` attribute that equals something like `@string/hello_world`.

Comment: @MikeM. yep i do that, i have problem with extend Activity but im need using setSupportActiobar (need AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 0):

Please select your theme without action bar feature, your theme like following,

if you have theme like `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`
Replace with `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

may be you used in menifest change it.

Comment: can you post your menifest file here ?

Comment: Thanks for help, check it first post already all you need on post

Answer (score 0):

OK, Try the following and let me know what happens.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: still same problem when im try open nav for calculator.java got unfortunately stopped